# How to connect DigitalOcean Function to MySQL?

Tags: python, function, digital-ocean

I have created a simple Python Function (section Functions and NOT Apps). The function needs to access the MySQL database (the database is also created on DigitalOcean). When running the function I get an error: "2023-04-15T13:55:42.402632917Z stderr: The function exceeded its time limits of 6000 milliseconds. Logs might be missing."

The function is very basic, so 6 sec should more than enough to run successfuly. When it is trying to connect to DB the timeout occurs somehow.

If I comment out the lines which connect to DB than the app runs just fine without errors.

Answer (score 0):

With help of DigitalOcean (DO) support the answer to my question is:

- if you use Function section in DO portal and you deploy your function to it, than use global variables defined in project.yml for using in connection string, ie:

> ```
> packages:
>     - name: alfaprogram
>       functions:
>         - name: t
>           runtime: python:default
>           web: false
> environment:
>   gE_MySQL_server: "you-find-that-on-DO-page"
>   gE_MySQL_database: "you-find-that-on-DO-page"
>   gE_MySQL_user: "you-find-that-on-DO-page"
>   gE_MySQL_password: "you-find-that-on-DO-page"
>   gE_MySQL_port: "you-find-that-on-DO-page"
> ```

- take into consideration the following file structure in your project:

> ```
>    .
> ├── packages
> │   └── alfaprogram
> │       └── t
> │           ├── build.sh
> │           ├── __main__.py
> │           └── requirements.txt
> └── project.yml
> ```

- (important) you have to delete all TRUSTED SOURCES from DB (setting in DO portal) and with that you open your DB to the world

**SUGGESTION:** better solution than using Functions in DO portal would be Apps where you can open access to DB for exact app only.